nullreferenceexception from ExecuteScalar()
I really don't know what to write here. I was just coding and this stuff happened.
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Categories where Name = @Name group by CategoryID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", categoryName);
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

it errors at
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

I am expecting it to return a value of 1, since there's 1 row in the Categories table. However, it just throws an exception.

Are you sure that you get the NRE there? I doubt it. Debug it

yep, it happens there.
https://imgur.com/a/gHmhcfz

Thanks to your "GROUP BY" clause, if there are no rows matched by the WHERE, your query will return no rows, not a single row of single column of 0. I would expect that to cause ExecuteScalar to explode because it's expecting a single value, one row, one column resultset. By the way, can you guarantee there will always only ever be one CategoryId for a Name? If not, your logic here may be faulty; if the same name exists with different categoryIDs then a multi line rowset will result, which ExecuteScalar cannot interpret

huh? i thought it'd just return 0 and that'd be the end of it

If no categories match your filter, null is returned instead of 0. Then you cast null to int which causes the NRE. So you have to handle that:
object? result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int count =  result == null || result == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int) result;

Maybe you could add it to an extension to avoid forgetting this:
public static class SqlCommandExtensions
{
    public static int ExecuteScalarToInt(this SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        object? result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return result == null || result == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)result;
    }
}

Now it's easy to use:
int count = cmd.ExecuteScalarToInt();

As to the why null is returned at all if you use COUNT(*):
You cannot expect any records to be returned when using a GROUP BY clause, when no records exist in your source. So with group by you are not counting the rows that exist after you filter by category-name(then you'd have to omit the GROUP BY), but you count the rows for each distinct category-name. Since your pre-filter does not return anything, you get null as result.
